# How to prevent El Capitan from opening new window of my app when open a file

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan

When using El Capitan and go to File --> Open, our app opens the file in a new window instead of in the existing window.

I've seen this in other apps under El Capitan too. For example, in TextEdit, if you open a new document, and then from that blank document open a saved document, TextEdit opens the saved document in a new window and leaves the original document open as a blank document. I never saw this happen prior to El Capitan so I'm wondering if it's a bug or an intentional design feature and if there's a known way to work around it programmatically.

Comment: I think it's intentional behavior.

Comment: If you use document based app then new window open since 10.7. Nothing has changed